# naming dimension tables in data warehouse

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I have a question about naming convention for dimension tables in data warehouse. I wonder it is a good idea to keep the type of dimension in the name. for example for dimension type 1 we will have something like this:

1. dim_scd1_student ( it is of slowly changing dimension type 1)
2. dim_scd2_teacher ( it is of slowly changing dimension type 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

Neither Dr. Ralph Kimball nor Christopher Adamson use this convention in their books. Both authors recommend this detail be documented in and managed from the ETL process.

End users, such as managers and business analysts, will interact with table and column names. The best of them will know how to construct simple SQL queries to get the business answers they seek. But slowly changing dimensions are implementation details and not relevant to them. A column name "dim_scd2_..." will only create confusion, questions, and noise. Remember, this system is designed for business people, not software engineers.

Also, I would omit the "dim" prefix. The business measurement or event tables should be suffixed with "fact" or "facts" (Kimball & Adamson use both). All other tables are by default dimensions.

Aside: doing what you suggest is similar to embedding the storage type into a programming language variable name. For example, in a C program, the "int" type could be used as follows: `int_customer_id`. But what if in the future "int" isn't big enough and we need to use "long"? Oops.

Comment: Sorry, maybe a blond question, however, querying an scd1 table does not require to check for a current_flag, while querying and scd2 table does. 

When using both scd1 and scd2 dimensions, wouldn't it just be handy to:
- name scd1 tables without suffix (channel)
- for each scd2 dimension, create a current view without suffix and an scd2 view with suffix (companies_sc + a view on companies_sc called just 'companies' that select only the current records)? 

this might prevent errors, since business users will be warned when a join with dates is required.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Users, including managers and business analysts, that interact with this table need to know the implementation detail of the table in order to be able to use it, since the way you would query for SCD2 vs SCD6 is different, and SCD6 supports historical queries which may not be possible with other SCD types